# DB solution for hybrid-mobile-app

Tags: angularjs, database, sqlite, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am going to build hybrid-mobile-app with Ionic, Angular and Cordova and port it to Android and iOS. One of the main features of the app will be offline storage/capability to store and view app content offline.

Content that I want to save in local DB may be even over 50MB, so local storage is not an option.

So far I found sqlite and indexdb. But I wonder if any of you have previous experience with similar problem to solve and could suggest some other options? Or maybe which option (sqlite or indexdb) will be better solution for my app?

Comment: Use this plugin for large databases: https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 3):

You should also know that localStorage isn't a viable option for permanent device storage if you're going to build for iOS. The OS will wipe out localStorage data when device memory is low. IndexDB may be volatile too because it's stored within the context of the webview.

I develop an Ionic app which has some data stored (not a large amount at the moment) in SQLite. I chose localForage with SQLite driver. It works well for what I need because it stores the data to a database file in the filesystem which is safe from OS deletion. What's nice is that the functions are similar to what you get with localStorage; the biggest difference being that the functions use promises.

This is the stack of components that I used in order to implement what I have now:

**Bower components**

- angular-localForage
- localforage
- localForage-cordovaSQLiteDriver

You will also need the [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) plugin.

Comment: You can make local storage properly persistent with Cordova, the framework manages this for you they fixed this a while back.

Comment: @SimonPrickett do you happen to have a link to that? The behavior was in iOS and not Cordova, so I'm not sure how they manage to avoid the OS from doing cleanup that it needs to do.

Comment: I have an app in the App Store that relies on this and it works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You may also have a look at [LokiJS](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-lokijs-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/) and [PouchDB](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/) (blog articles from "GoneHybrid", implementing those 2 libs).

I would personally go for LokiJS (http://lokijs.org/) and its JSON file, even if both have adapters for WebSQL, SQLite, IndexedDB.

Answer (score 2):

I was part of a team that built a successful Cordova / Sencha Touch (the UI framework doesn't really matter here) / SQLite app for iOS and Android.  We had over 100Mb of data to store in the database, had to encrypt it and transfer it from a server into the app.

SQLite performed well, we also used some custom functions that we wrote to move some of the data crunching we needed into the database engine and out of Javascript.

Another member of the team wrote a [short blog article](http://moduscreate.com/hybrid-mobile-apps-with-sqlite/) about some of our experiences with this stack.

Overall given my experience, I'd say SQLite is a sound choice, but I don't have experience with IndexDB.